# How to make Slack remember its position on screen?

Tags: windows-10, slack

When I start the Windows Slack app, I position it in the left half of the monitor. As long as I switch between apps, minimize Slack, bring it up front again, it remembers its position.

But when I close the window (Slack continues to run in tray) and reopen it, it appears in a different location on screen. Same happens if I sign out, sign in and start the app, and also after reboot, etc.

How do I make Slack remember its position and always appear there?
(The window's size it does remember though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently impossible, according to Slack support (I asked them about it today):

> Unfortunately this is a problem we currently have with the Windows
>   app, and I'm sorry it is getting in your way.
>
> We do have it on our list to address, and hopefully that will roll out
>   as you update in the near future. I can't provide an ETA, but if you'd
>   like I can follow up as we resolve this one.

Answer (score 2):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-apps-do-not-remember-size-and-position/6ed3fe70-8935-407e-ad47-d98f920c03c9

SeanMann_NaplandGames Replied on November 30, 2015
OK, so I just found a workaround.

Open the app and position and size it on monitor 2
Move the app to monitor 1
Close the app
Relaunch the app, it should retain its size and position on monitor 1
Move the app to the desired position on monitor 2 
Relaunch the app and all should be green
Let's just hope it continues to work on reboot.

Comment: Wow, I've tried everything, but this actually worked. Thx!

Comment: By 'close the app' do you mean close the window, or quit the app from the tray?